# hibernate composite key hql insert bulk

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

I have tables with composite keys in existing database. When I want to use bulk-insert in HQL like "INSERT INTO entityName (id.key1 id.key2, property1, property, ...) SELECT prop1, prop2, prop3, prop3 FROM entityName2" I get error: Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property ...

If my entity for the "insert into"-statement has only one id-column everything works like a charm.

I use hibernate-entitymanager version 4.3.6.

First the entity for the insert-clause:

```
package de.kbv.rms;
// Generated 30.07.2014 10:31:56 by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1


import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.AttributeOverride;
import javax.persistence.AttributeOverrides;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.EmbeddedId;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

/**
 * Dm1Dap generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="DM1_DAP"
)
public class Dm1Dap  implements java.io.Serializable {

     @EmbeddedId
    @AttributeOverrides( {
        @AttributeOverride(name="dmpFallNr", column=@Column(name="DMP_FALL_NR", nullable=false, length=10) ), 
        @AttributeOverride(name="anr", column=@Column(name="ANR", nullable=false, length=14) ), 
        @AttributeOverride(name="versNr", column=@Column(name="VERS_NR", nullable=false, length=21) ), 
        @AttributeOverride(name="kassenNr", column=@Column(name="KASSEN_NR", nullable=false, length=10) ) } )
    private Dm1DapId id;

    // ... columns with getters and setters.
```

the composite-key for the DAP-Entity:

```
package de.kbv.rms;
// Generated 30.07.2014 10:31:56 by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1


import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;

/**
 * Dm1DapId generated by hbm2java
 */
@Embeddable
public class Dm1DapId  implements java.io.Serializable {



    @Column(name="DMP_FALL_NR", nullable=false, length=10)
    private String dmpFallNr;

    @Column(name="ANR", nullable=false, length=14)
    private String anr;

    @Column(name="VERS_NR", nullable=false, length=21)
    private String versNr;

    @Column(name="KASSEN_NR", nullable=false, length=10)
    private String kassenNr;

    // columns with getters and setters
     ...
    // equals and hash-Methods 
     ...
```

my entity for the select-clause. I tested select-clause separately and it works without problems.

```
package de.kbv.rms;
// Generated 30.07.2014 10:31:56 by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.AttributeOverride;
import javax.persistence.AttributeOverrides;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.EmbeddedId;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

/**
 * Dm1F generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="DM1_F"
)
public class Dm1F  implements java.io.Serializable {



     @EmbeddedId
    @AttributeOverrides( {
        @AttributeOverride(name="DmpFallNr", column=@Column(name="F_DMP_FALL_NR", nullable=false, length=10) ), 
        @AttributeOverride(name="Anr", column=@Column(name="F_ANR", nullable=false, length=14) ), 
        @AttributeOverride(name="DokuDatum", column=@Column(name="F_DOKU_DATUM", nullable=false, length=7) ) } )
    private Dm1FId id;

// ... columns with getters and setters.
```

my composite-key for the Dm1F-Entity:

```
package de.kbv.rms;
// Generated 30.07.2014 10:31:56 by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1

import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

/**
 * Dm1FId generated by hbm2java
 */
@Embeddable
public class Dm1FId  implements java.io.Serializable {

    @Column(name="F_DMP_FALL_NR", nullable=false, length=10)
    private String DmpFallNr;

    @Column(name="F_ANR", nullable=false, length=14)
    private String Anr;

    @Temporal (TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name="F_DOKU_DATUM", nullable=false, length=7)
    private Date DokuDatum;

    // columns with getters and setters
    ...
    // equals and hash-Methods 
    ...
```

my JUNIT-Test:

```
package dao.test;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.Query;

import org.junit.Test;

public class RmsSimpleTest {

    public static EntityManager entityManager = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("devsample")
            .createEntityManager();

    @Test
    public void testQuery() {
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();

        Query query = entityManager
                .createQuery("INSERT INTO  Dm1Dap (id.dmpFallNr, id.anr, id.versNr, id.kassenNr) SELECT f.id.DmpFallNr, f.id.Anr, f.VersNr, f.KassenNr FROM Dm1F f");

        query.executeUpdate();

        long estimatedTime = java.lang.System.nanoTime() - startTime;
        System.out.println(" Time: "
                + String.format("%d milsec", TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(estimatedTime)));
    }
}
```

stacktrace snippet:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property:  of: de.kbv.rms.Dm1Dap [INSERT INTO  Dm1Dap (id.dmpFallNr, id.anr, id.versNr, id.kassenNr) SELECT f.id.DmpFallNr, f.id.Anr, f.VersNr, f.KassenNr FROM de.kbv.rms.Dm1F f]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1750)
```

DEBUG-Snippet:

```
4016 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl  - parse() - HQL: INSERT INTO  Dm1Dap (id.dmpFallNr, id.anr, id.versNr, id.kassenNr) SELECT f.id.DmpFallNr, f.id.Anr, f.VersNr, f.KassenNr FROM de.kbv.rms.Dm1F f
4038 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl  - --- HQL AST ---
 \-[INSERT] Node: 'INSERT'
    +-[INTO] Node: 'INTO'
    |  +-[IDENT] Node: 'Dm1Dap'
    |  \-[RANGE] Node: 'column-spec'
    |     +-[DOT] Node: '.'
    |     |  +-[IDENT] Node: 'id'
    |     |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'dmpFallNr'
    |     +-[DOT] Node: '.'
    |     |  +-[IDENT] Node: 'id'
    |     |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'anr'
    |     +-[DOT] Node: '.'
    |     |  +-[IDENT] Node: 'id'
    |     |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'versNr'
    |     \-[DOT] Node: '.'
    |        +-[IDENT] Node: 'id'
    |        \-[IDENT] Node: 'kassenNr'
    \-[QUERY] Node: 'query'
       \-[SELECT_FROM] Node: 'SELECT_FROM'
          +-[FROM] Node: 'FROM'
          |  \-[RANGE] Node: 'RANGE'
          |     +-[DOT] Node: '.'
          |     |  +-[DOT] Node: '.'
          |     |  |  +-[DOT] Node: '.'
          |     |  |  |  +-[IDENT] Node: 'de'
          |     |  |  |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'kbv'
          |     |  |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'rms'
          |     |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'Dm1F'
          |     \-[ALIAS] Node: 'f'
          \-[SELECT] Node: 'SELECT'
             +-[DOT] Node: '.'
             |  +-[DOT] Node: '.'
             |  |  +-[IDENT] Node: 'f'
             |  |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'id'
             |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'DmpFallNr'
             +-[DOT] Node: '.'
             |  +-[DOT] Node: '.'
             |  |  +-[IDENT] Node: 'f'
             |  |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'id'
             |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'Anr'
             +-[DOT] Node: '.'
             |  +-[IDENT] Node: 'f'
             |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'VersNr'
             \-[DOT] Node: '.'
                +-[IDENT] Node: 'f'
                \-[IDENT] Node: 'KassenNr'

4038 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter  - throwQueryException() : no errors
4065 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker  - insert << begin [level=1, statement=insert]
4071 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter  - <AST>:1:24: unexpected AST node: .
4071 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter  - <AST>:1:24: unexpected AST node: .
<AST>:1:24: unexpected AST node: .
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.insertablePropertySpec(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:986)
```

Is there any way to use bulk-insert and composite-keys in hibernate?

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround you should add the composite-id properties directly to the entity and set them to `insertable = false and updateable = false`. There is no need to add getter/setter for that properties.

```
@Column(name = "F_DMP_FALL_NR", insertable = false, updateable = false)
private String DmpFallNr;
```

The *insert into select* bulk operation do not check this options. Now you can remove the id prefix and use the properties directly in your HQL query.

```
INSERT INTO Dm1Dap (idmpFallNr, anr, versNr, kassenNr) SELECT f.id.DmpFallNr, f.id.Anr, f.VersNr, f.KassenNr FROM Dm1F f
```